# Setting up org-mode tags with groups

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, tags

Running in `emacs -Q` I set up this file and added it to my agenda

```
#+TAGS: [ toptag : subtag ]

* headline 1 :toptag:
* headline 2 :subtag:
* headline 3
```

`org-tag-alist` now has value `(("[") ("toptag") (:grouptags) ("subtag") ("]"))`

[Per the docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tag-hierarchy.html), I should now be able to <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> `toptag` <kbd>RET</kbd> to find headlines matching either `toptag` org `subtag`.

But it only finds headline 1, tagged `toptag`. Wondering if I'd interpreted it backwards, I also tried  <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> `subtag` <kbd>RET</kbd>, but that only finds `headline 2`, tagged `subtag`.

How do I set this up and search to find a tag and all its children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Rainer Königs video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odOKnNDKSIs&index=36&list=PLVtKhBrRV_ZkPnBtt_TD1Cs9PJlU0IIdE). He described the solution of your problem in excess.

Rainers solution: using org mode version >=8.3, since tag hierarchies were introduced with org 8.3.

Comment: @Stefan, the solution is to use at least org mode version 8.3. I'm not sure how to improve the answer. I had the same problem, updated my org mode and that's how it worked for me.

Comment: Oh, duh, sorry I misunderstood your answer.